# Images display issue in Dynamics AX 2009 reports saved as pdf

Tags: pdf, dynamics-ax-2009

When i saved a native Dynamics AX 2009 report as pdf or pdf-embed it doesn't show the images in the report i.e. company logo in header section, properly. The image comes very distorted, grayish and repeated.

On the other if i export the image in HTML format the image comes properly.
Had anyone experience a similar issue.

Please note that im saving the report as pdf using "file" option that comes when the report print dialog opens.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please state the format of the image you are using.  
I've had this same problem but not investigated the issue any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Issue will go if the image format used is one of the following
1. 24bit Bitmap
2. TIFF
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this issue in AX 2009:

```
Bitmap getImageBitmap(ItemId _itemId)
{
    HPLInventImages inventImages; // Column HPLInventImages.ItemImage is EDT:BlobData (which is a container)
    Image image;
    ;

    if (!_itemId) return inventImages.ItemImage; // Return null bitmap. The whole AX client crashes if you try to do the resizing code below on a null bitmap.

    select firstonly inventImages where inventImages.ItemId==_itemId;
    //return inventImages.ItemImage; // Would normally just do this, but see comments below.

    // Ok, this next bit is weird!
    // There is a known issue with AX reports with images in, getting saved as PDFs:
    // In some cases, the images appear as garbage on the PDF.
    // I have found that resizing the image before rendering it, causes the image to come out ok on the PDF.
    // So the code below does a token resize (by 1.0 times!) operation on the image before returning it.
    // That is enough to make the image on the PDF turn out ok.
    image=new Image(inventImages.ItemImage);
    image.resize(image.width()*1.0,image.height()*1.0,InterpolationMode::InterpolationModeHighQuality);
    return image.getData();
}
```